# Get or Set Cell Values in a Datagrid progmatically

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, flex4

In Flex 4 using a pre populated data grid, how can I get or set specific values programatically, IE I wont be using selectedItems etc.

How do I reference the value of a cell in row 4 colum 6 for example.

Please and thank you in advance for your help.

Craig

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cast the *dataProvider* of the DataGrid to `ListCollectionView` and use its [getItemAt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#getItemAt%28%29) method.

```
ListCollectionView(dataGrid.dataProvider).getItemAt(requiredRow).appropriateProperty = newValue;
```

Update: In case the column name is dynamic, you can fetch it using something like:

```
var data_field:String = dgViewPreview.columns[6].dataField; //for 6th column
ListCollectionView(dataGrid.dataProvider).getItemAt(requiredRow)[data_field] = newValue;
```

Comment: Firstly thankk you so much for taking the time to answer:Ok that gets me the row, how do I get the specific column

Comment: I have 30 values in a single row I really only want to update only one specific item.

Comment: The scenario is when a user edits an item in my datagrid, I need to update a series of other values in the datagrid which in turn are running totals of certain othr vlaues of the grid.

Comment: would this work: ListCollectionView(dataGrid.dataProvider).getItemAt(requiredColumn,requiredRow).appropriateProperty = newValue; 

And what is the appropriateProperty for the value of a cell.

I have not being able to find any decent documentation on working with cells beyond selectedItem. Which does not apply to anything Im trying to do?

Comment: @Craig it depends on what value you show in that particular column - that's why I used the term `appropriateProperty` - what's the `dataField` of the required DataGridColumn?

Comment: Well the grid in question is more of a pivot, that I build to an indeterminable size.

I dont want to change the data for the entire column I just want to evaluate each indvidual CELL and then change its value as needed.

Comment: @Craig Can you post the relevant code - of the DataGrid and desired column's?

Comment: So imagine that if user changes the cell in Row 6 Column4 I might potentially Update the cell correspoding to Row 1 column 4, Row 2 Column 4

Comment: MXML - http://pastebin.com/e3mSxd1i

mydata.xml - http://pastebin.com/RV0D6Y5j

You will see that I build the structure up depending on my data which can vary considerably depending on some external factor and data on the day.

But the intent is if a user edits one value a number of other values need to be updated.

Comment: @Craig The way it works is like this: there'll be a data provider with many objects in it. Each object will have a set of properties. These properties are shown in columns - the mapping between column and property is done using the `dataField` attribute of the corresponding DataGridColumn. So, if you know, the name of the particular property of the data that is displayed in column-6, you can update that property to update the column.

Comment: Ok but if I update DataField,it will change all values in that column to what ever the dataprovider says. (the dataField being a global provider for all items in that column).

As appose to just one specific item in that column.

Hmm Ok change of approach:

If I update the a field I have updated the provider.

How would I set a specific cell value at a specific column&row in the provider?

Surely I could alter the grid by altering the provider the grid would change automatically.

Comment: So what would be the syntax to edit the value of a specific cell at Row 4 Column 3 in the provider?

Comment: @Amarghosh - Thank you soo much I think I can make that work to walk the array lists, and do the updates, the company I work at is excel obsessed i can see by the end of this I would have practically built excel in flex lol. thank you so much.

Comment: I presume getItemAt(requiredRow) = getItemAt(6) where by 6 is the ordinal reference to the row number.

Comment: There should be a button where I can give you a medal or something, that code works perfectly :)

Comment: @Craig You can upvote my answer by clicking the up-arrow `^` button near top-left corner of the answer ;)

Comment: Great job Amarghosh! This helped me very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to access, based on Grid column DataField Mapping to object property or LabelFunction set to grid column

I pasted the scenario with example here
http://pastebin.com/iwrnHD1c